# HttpResponseMessage do you dispose it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

Whilst waiting for the new shiny `HttpClientFactory` addressing all the issues of `HttpClient`,

I still cannot find an answer whether `HttpResponseMessage` and `HttpRequestMessage` should be disposed.

Is something like below a good practice?

Do you use a Using statement with `HttpResponseMessage`?

```
//httpClient has been injected

using (HttpResponseMessage messageResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    using (HttpContent content = messageResponse.Content)
    {
        if (messageResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json  = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var response = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(json, serializerSettings));

            return new MyWrapperResponse<TResponse>(messageResponse,response);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you use a Using statement with HttpResponseMessage?

Short Answer: Yes you can.

> Is something like below a good practice?

It depends.

While it is usually advised practice to wrap `IDisposable` derived classes with `using` for proper disposal, the example shown may be using it incorrectly.

The `messageResponse` is being injected into a wrapper class (`MyWrapperResponse`) and then the function returns immediately after. If the response message is being used outside of that wrapper's constructor, it is possible that the response would have already been disposed.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. The reason of this question is because HttpClient in its current form it should not be disposed even though it implements IDisposible,wondering if the same applies to HttpResponseMessage

Comment: @developer9969 no the same does not apply to `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage`. You can safely dispose of the request and response messages.

Comment: Thanks makes sense